# jQuery tabs . . . how do I change the css of a tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs

Currently I use:

```
<div id="tabs" class="basictab">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#fragment-1" id="Beta"><span>B.E.T.A. Plans</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#fragment-2" id="Mini"><span>Mini-Sites</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#fragment-3" id="Independent"><span>Independent Sites</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#fragment-4" id="Tools"><span>Tools</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="fragment-1" class="tabcontainer">
                        <nav:beta runat="server" ID="beta1" Visible="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="fragment-2" class="tabcontainer">
                        <nav:mini runat="server" ID="mini1" Visible="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="fragment-3" class="tabcontainer">

                    </div>
                    <div id="fragment-4" class="tabcontainer">
                        <nav:tools runat="server" ID="tools2" Visible="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({event: 'mouseover'});
    $tabs.tabs("select", 3);
  });
    </script>
```

to select a specific tab.  When I do this how do I change the css of the selected tab?  Wouldn't I want to chain off the

```
$tabs.tabs("select",3);
```

I have tried:

```
$tabs.tabs("select",3).removeClass('basictab').addClass('basictabactive');
```

but this changes the css for ALL the classes.

Many thanks in advance from a jQuery n00b.

Answer (score 2):

Add a select or load handler (depending on when you want it to fire) that adds the CSS or class to the component that you want to change.

```
 var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                 event: 'mouseover',
                 select: function(event,ui) {
                             $(ui.panel).css({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff'});
                         });
             });
```

It might be easier to just use the existing classes for the tabs, though, and adjust the CSS for the tab container.

```
#tabs .ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#tabs .ui-state-active {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#tabs .ui-state-default {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: will that work?  I am looking to change the CSS of the specific . . . Seleccted tab.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Thanks for the assistance but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Are you trying to change the "tab" -- the bit with the link -- or the "tab" the bit with the content.  I believe that ui.panel is a reference to the content.  If you want to change the former, use `ui.tab`.  Poke around with it in Firebug if the selector doesn't seem to be grabbing the exact element that you are needing.  You can also use the various `ui` properties as the context for other selectors if it's just a subcomponent that you need to change.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Thank you, but either it is not correct, or I implemented it incorrectly, please see my edits . . .

Comment: Now that I see what you are doing, why don't you just add/replace the appropriate styles for `ui-state-default`, `ui-state-highlight`, and `ui-state-active` for the tab container?

Comment: that sounds great . . . as a n00b how do I do it? </embarassment>

Comment: Add a stylesheet that gets loaded after the jQuery UI stylesheet -- you do have the jQuery UI stylesheet being loaded, right?  Use the syntax (or similar) that I've added to my answer to adjust the default styles.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
$(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
```

This will change the class on your item.

Comment: again, this requires a reference gleaned through a click event (as per the website the you pointed me to).  There is no click event for me to bind to, I am programatically selected a tab based upon the page they are on.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about that here:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/

Comment: I did read the website . . . but it is triggering off the click event for the tab, I have a submenu that is based on the tabs, when i .('select', 1), to select the tab, I want to change the css of that tab . . . NOT on a click event.  I do appreciate your assistance though.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Firefox with Firebug extension, you can inspect the live page element, to see what class it currently have.

In your code, the element with class `basictab` is the tabs parent `div`. Your code will change it's class. If you want to change only the current active class, inspect it using Firebug. Current jQuery-UI implementation will change the selected `li` class to have class `ui-tabs-selected`.

If you purpose to change the element's class is to apply the css, maybe it's simpler for you to create css for `ui-tabs-selected` class, instead to change it, since it will make you write extra js code only for something that can be done with css alone.