# Change css of active accordion and parent tab in jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am kinda new to jquery so have confusion regarding how to select the parent tab or just add effect on the current accordion. Whatever code I write within the script in the php condition is not making any visible change in the css of .ui-widget-header, most likely because I'm not selecting the parent element itself.

Let me give the necessary snippet of my code

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="accordion">

       <div> Some content </div>
       <div> 
           <?php  
           //Perform some query
           if (mysqli_num_rows($query)==0)
           //Make background of current accordion, and parent tab red. Add jquery script here
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'> </script>";//No clue what should be within this script, hence blank...
//Probably something like  $("accordion").parent("#tabs").css( background-color: red;background-image: none;)
//OR $(this).parents('div#tabs').css( background-color: red;background-image: none;)
           ?> 
       </div>
       <div>
          2nd accordion. There should be no effect here. 
       </div>
   </div>
   .....
```

A modfiied snipped is available on - jsfiddle.net/buKLE/8 ...Currently just tabs, and accordion. If possible, try and change the css of just tab1, supposing there is an error in accordion Section 2.
Is it going to be even possible to change the color of just that accordion, since all the accordions are bound together here...

Comment: I cannot see any javascript code in your tags?

Comment: Edit: Can you show us some of your code you tried?

Comment: I am clueless, as to how I should be selecting that parent tab, and then changing it's css properties. Pretty sure this is all wrong but just edited what I thought it would be like.

Comment: Don't be afraid to post that code in your question, this helps a lot by answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, you have two little errors in your code.

You missed the hash sign, and took the wrong traversing method:

```
               ↓ only traverses one level up
$("accordion").parent("#tabs")
```

should be:

```
   ↓ hash       ↓ traverses upwards, until the selector matches or top is reached
$("#accordion").parents("#tabs")
```

Comment: I can't see any visible change when I do this $("#accordion").parent("#tabs").css( background-color: red;)....Don't we have to add and remove class in jQuery UI? Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020995/jquery-tabs-how-do-i-change-the-css-of-a-tab

Comment: This depends on what exactly you want to do. You don't need to work with classes, if you just want to change a single css declaration (e.g. the border). Can you please prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and explain exactly what you want?

Comment: Here we go - http://jsfiddle.net/buKLE/8/ ...Currently just tabs, and accordion. Try and change the css of just tab1, supposing there is an error in accordion Section 2.

Comment: Take a look at [this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/buKLE/11/) if it helps you. If you want to have a particular element not changed, just comment out the according line with the `adderror()`. CLick on the content to trigger the change. I wourked with the native jQuery UI class `ui-state-error` here. For any further questions, just write a comment.

Comment: Thanks but got stuck again after making a few necessary changes. I supposed there was an error in Tab1-Section 2, so just added the script there. Only the content outside's color changed. Why didn't the CSS of the headers change? http://jsfiddle.net/buKLE/13/

Comment: `this` only points to the correct dom-element if it is inside an eventhandler (like `.click()`). In my example `this` is bound by the click-event to the dom-element you click on. In your example you have no eventhandler and that's why `this` points to the global object (which basically is nonsense) and thus calling `.attr("aria-labelledby")` fails.

Comment: But i don't want an even-handler like click() or focus(). It basically has to change color on the basis of the outcome of the php script, so that the user knows where there is an error. Is there an event-handler for this sort of purpose? Something related to load?

Comment: Why don't you set the class directly on the element then? Alternatively replace `this` with a variable name and write `var elem = "ui-accordion-accordion-panel-#";` in the script block where `#` is the number of your panel.

Comment: I have asked you way too many questions. Hopefully I will figure it out soon else.... Anyways help some other guy now. Thanks anyways. :-)

Comment: Hey, can you help further? Thought you are familiar with this, so might as well pick your head - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133957/

Comment: Please, don't bother....adderror : function(){var errorstate = "ui-state-error";this.toggleClass(errorstate);}...All I'd to was change that to addClass instead of ToggleClass. The problem was with even number of errors in the same tab, the tab's error state was being toggled off.